# Rspec 3.8 before block not deleting record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

In `app/models/car.rb` the class method `stock` looks in part like this:

```
 def self.stock
   raise Exception, "Property amount not set" if Property.get(:amount).nil?
   ...
 end
```

This Property is accessable by the user through all CRUD operations.
I now want to test that if that Property is truly deleted an standard expection should be thrown. Therefore i created in my rspec model the following example group

```
describe '.stock' do

  describe 'if property is not set' do
    before(:all) {Property.where(name: 'amount').map(&:destroy)}
    it 'raises an exception' do
      expect{Car.stock}.to raise_error (Exception)
    end 
    after (:all) {Property.create! name: 'amount', value: 10}
  end 

  describe 'if property is set' do
    before (:all) do  
      create :car_listed
      create :car_sold
    end 
    it 'calculates the correct amount of sellable cars' do
      amount = 10 - Car.where(state: "sold")
      expect(Car.stock).to eq(amount)
    end 
  end 
end
```

I make sure all Properties with that name get deleted. In the it-block i then expect the exception to be trown. After the it-block i created the property again because other tests depend on it.

In the app are properties which are not going to change during tests. So `database_cleaner` does not truncate the properties table. It got set through a seeds file.

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {except: %w[properties]}
end
```

The test however fails with

```
Car
 .stock
   if property is set
    calculates the correct amount of sellable cars
   if property is not set
    raises an exception (FAILED - 1)

 Failures:

  1) Car.stock if property is not set not set raises an exception
      Failure/Error: expect{Car.stock}.to raise_error (Exception)
      expected Exception but nothing was raised
      # ./spec/models/car_spec.rb: `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My question is now how do i have to delete this property properly ((:), so that my exception gets raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are easier ways to test this that do not touch the database. Here's how to approach the problem using stubs:

```
describe '.stock' do
  before do
    allow(Property).to receive(:get).with(:amount).and_return(amount)
  end

  context 'when property amount is NOT set' do
    let(:amount) { nil }

    it 'raises an exception' do
      expect { Car.stock }.to raise_error(Exception)
    end
  end

  context 'when amount property is set' do
    let(:amount) { 10 }

    before do
      create :car_listed
      create :car_sold
    end

    it 'does NOT raise an exception' do
      expect { Car.stock }.to_not raise_error(Exception)
    end

    it 'calculates the correct amount of sellable cars' do
      expect(Car.stock).to eq(amount - 1)
    end 
  end
```

NOTE: I'm unsure about that last test since you didn't include that code.

Comment: Excellent. I have not really used stubs deeply. But this is a nice beginning.Thanks!